# How to change Device ID without Root?

Tags: factory-reset

So, there is an app, 9chat. I was using it for a while, then out of nowhere, the app started to give me error: "Invalid user ID and Token!"

I have LG G3 D855.

I tried everything to log in to app again (restart, reinstal, changing account, etc) , yet nothing worked, then I used another Android device, and I had no problem. Even with same user and pass.

The problem is so rare, that there is no way to solve it from my side. But the developers don't help either, I saw people were not be able to log in more than a month.

And then I thought maybe factory reset, will help, so I get back up, then reseted. I did 4 factory reset, each time using different Google Account, yet each time, after installing 9 chat as the first thing, I got the error "Invalid User ID and token!"

The weirdest thing, is the app says "welcome back *username* blah blah blah" then says invalid token. And the other app of this company, 9GAG works fine, without any problem, using same accounts.

So, I need to change Device ID. I have latest stock Lollipop, so I can't root, and I don't like other roms. Is there any thing that can help me here? I don't need the app, I just want to win.

Comment: Wrong question. Samsung aren't making good stock ROMs... Are you sure that 9chat fails to connect to 9gag account?

Comment: I'm not Samsung either, I'm LG G3. LoL. Yeah, it fails because of my Device ID, that's why I have to change Device ID.

Comment: I know. Oh, just my phone lagged. That must be impossible without root on any phone, so I think there is no answer

Comment: Consider to update the problem from your post on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/help/app-blocks-phone-t3071583).

Comment: Have you tried wiping the davlic cache when resetting? Go here for more info on that http://androidforums.com/threads/should-i-wipe-dalvik-cache-on-lollipop.916170/. If that does not work try encrypting the phone THEN doing a factory reset/wipe.